# jQuery Datepicker - select only few days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried to make my datepicker better, but i only managed to enable (first i disabled all) mondays and thursdays but now i have a problem with specific dates. I tried many posibilities but either select 21th in every month or doesn't work at all.

Now im trying to enable that date (2013,04,21) (and later maybe more of them)

```
  $( '#vfb-datum-75' ).datepicker({
              beforeShowDay: settings,
  });  

  function settings(date) {
      if (date.getDay() == 1)       
          { return [true, "","Works"];
      } else if (date.getDay() == 4)
          { return [true, "","Works"];
      } else if (date.getDate() == (2013,04,21))  <-- this doesn't work
          { return [true, "","Works"];
      } else { return [false,"",""]; 
  }}
```

thanks for help.

Comment: We'll need a bit more information to figure this out.

Comment: Do you want to enable certain dates, disable certain dates? What is your objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f7kAc/

You can compare the year, day, and month.  Remember that month is zero based.

```
date.getDate() == 21 && date.getMonth() == 3 && date.getFullYear() == 2013
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7kAc/1/

You can campare the date to another date using this method also.

```
date - new Date(2013, 3, 21) == 0
```

BUT, if you are going to grow this function to have 50+ special dates, you might want something a little snappier, and easier to configure.

```
var specialDays = 
{2013 : 
  {
      3 : 
          {
              21 : [true, "", "WORKS"]
          },
      4 : 
          {
              15 : [true, "", "WORKS"],
              17 : [true, "", "WORKS"]
          },
  },
};
```

Then in your function:

```
... else if (!!specialDays[date.getYear()] && !!specialDays[date.getYear()][date.getMonth()] && !!specialDays[date.getYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()]) {
  return specialDays[date.getYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fot all these solutions ;)